# Who were the two large hobbits?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, hobbits

In the *Lord of the Rings* chapter "The Scouring of the Shire", there is this passage:

> The hobbits at the gate still seemed ill at ease, evidently some rule or other was being broken; but there was no gainsaying four such masterful travelers, all armed, and two of them uncommonly large and strong looking.

Which of the hobbits, Frodo, Sam, Merry, or Pippin, are uncommonly large and strong looking?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Merry and Pippin.

Both had benefited from Treebeard's Ent-draught, as described in "Flight to the Ford" (in The Fellowship of The Ring):

> You are thirsty I expect. Perhaps you are also tired. Drink this!' He
> went to the back of the bay, and then they saw that several tall stone
> jars stood there, with heavy lids. He removed one of the lids, and
> dipped in a great ladle, and with it filled three bowls, one very
> large bowl, and two smaller ones. ...

Then when some of the company reunite later, in "The Field of Cormallen" (in The Return of the King):

> But amidst all these wonders [Sam] returned always to his astonishment
> at the size of Merry and Pippin; and he made them stand back to back
> with Frodo and himself. He scratched his head. 'Can't understand it at
> your age!' he said. 'But there it is: you're three inches taller than
> you ought to be, or I'm a dwarf.'

> [Gimli] 'But what did I say? Mortals cannot go drinking
> ent-draughts and expect no more to come of them than of a pot of
> beer.'

Comment: There’s a passage in the appendices about how Pippin and Merry were the tallest Hobbits on record.

Comment: @Shamshiel: taller than Bandobras Bullroarer Took!

Comment: See also Pippin's line *"I am but four feet, and not likely to grow any more, save sideways"*. Tolkien has said elsewhere that Hobbits tended to average 3'6".

Comment: Thanks @yoniLavi . It seems silly that I'd not done that myself as I spend much time curating telling other people to include references :)

Comment: It was also largely cut from the theatrical version of the films so the youthful mind is more likely to have missed it.

Comment: Why does Gimli know what ent-draught is? Seems unlikely knowledge for a dwarf.

Comment: Presumably this is after Gandalf has told him various things about it and Gimli was dwarfsplaining?